# Calling JavaScript async function in for loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a `for` loop and I want to call an async function on each iteration. But I am getting a JS stack trace error. Below is the prototype of my code. I have also used IIFE pattern but it's not working.

```
for(let i = 0; i<99999;i++){
  getData(i, function(err, result){
      if(err) return err;
      else{
       console.log(result);
      }
  });
}
function getData(number, callback){
  request('http://someapiurl'+number, function(err, response){
     if(err) callback(err, null);
     else{
      callback(null, response)
     }
  })
}
```

Comment: If you want to wait for the result of getData before executing the next iteration of the loop, you cannot use a for loop.

Answer (score -1):

You re trying to make 99999 at the same time, this just won t work on most browsers.

Use promises instead, push them in an array, then use Promise.all to let the browser handle the request, simply handle the final resolved response.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```
var p1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var p2 = 1337;
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
}); 

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(values => { 
  console.log(values); // [3, 1337, "foo"] 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all I highly suggest that you debug your code to see exactly what happens with the for loop.

Its very likely that the loop runs completely before its contents (the `getData` function) executes, asynchronous behavior of via a fetching data request. If you tried using the IIFE pattern you'd have at least wrapped the contents inside your for loop in a way that guarantees its contents to execute. An example of an implementation looks like so:

```
for(let i = 0; i<99999;i++){
  (function(){ // <-- IIFE used to represent a closure.
    getData(i, function(err, result){
      if(err) return err;
        else{
          console.log(result);
        }
    });
  })(i);
}
```

To let [@mika](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45042996/1046690) sit on the subject of promises for you, which you can read on their answer; just keep in mind the promise anti-pattern and you'll be fine. It is especially tricky if you are not used to promises and want to use them in a for loop.